# Encontrar em um texto as tags img

Tags: php

Eu possuo um texto Aleatório:

```
$s = " eu sou campeao <img src='leo.jpg' /> teste lala  ";
```

e preciso que adicione o caminho da imagem e fique assim:

```
$s = " eu sou campeao <img src='img/leo.jpg' /> teste lala  ";
```

Obs: eu preciso adicionar "img/" dentro do src que possui o diretorio. Pode vir varias imagens, mas vou adicionar a mesma string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php), para trocar o `src='` por `src='img/'`.

```
str_replace('src=\'', 'src=\'img/', $s);
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2c5e5d1ed31a626baa59a38db2a5efd89b0b84e)